# Substract 2 size_t ... some weird results

Tags: size-t

Here is my code :

```
std::cout << _cSample << " - " << _bSample 
             << " = " << (_cSample - _bSample) << std::endl;
```

The output gives me : `3525 - 150000 = 18446744073709405141`
and i still don't know why ? Maybe because they're unsigned ?

How do i substract 2 size_t ? Here i'd like to get a basic substract result
i searched on the internet without success.

Thank you !

see for output : puu.sh/lbPW5/5f998c0c02.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly because they are unsigned.  You need to cast both to a signed type in order to get a signed result.  For example:

```
std::cout << _cSample << " - " << _bSample 
         << " = " << ((__int64)_cSample - (__int64)_bSample) << std::endl;
```

The actual signed type you use will depend on your compiler.  Beware that casting an unsigned type to a signed type that isn't larger will result in data loss.